# Debug Assertion Failed c++ deque iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++

i want my code to do infix to prefix change. when the input is 3+5 the output should be 35+. however when i type "3+5"t the program shows 3 at console screen and then an error pops. Error says *"Debug Assertion Failed!...microsoft visual studio10.0\vc\include\deque **line:338** Expression : "Deque iterator not dereferencable* when i click on "ignore" another error pops. *"Debug Assertion Failed!...microsoft visual studio10.0\vc\include\deque **line:339** Expression :"standart c++ libraries out of range"&&0* Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string>
#include<locale>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
```

> the function that decides priority

```
int priority(char a)
{
int prio=-1;
if(a=='+'||a=='-')
    prio=1;
else if(a=='*'||a=='/')
    prio=2;
else if(a=='^')
    prio=3;
else if(a=='(')
    prio=4;
return prio;
}

void main()
{int i=0,j=0;
int control=0;
string infix;
stack<char> ostack;
vector<char> temp;
cin>>infix;

for(i=0;i<infix.length();i++)
    {
```

> if it is a number i want to print it

```
    if(isdigit(infix[i]))
    {
        cout<<infix[i];
    }
```

> if it is a math symbol i want to check which one

```
    else if(infix[i]=='+' || infix[i]=='-' || infix[i]=='*' || infix[i]=='/' || infix[i]=='^' || infix[i]=='(')
    {
        if(priority(infix[i])>priority(ostack.top()) || ostack.empty())
        {
            ostack.push(infix[i]);
        }
        else if(priority(infix[i])<=priority(ostack.top()))
        {    
            while(!ostack.empty())
            {
            temp.push_back(ostack.top());
            cout<<ostack.top();
            ostack.pop();
            }
        control++;
        }
        else if(control=1)
        {
        ostack.push(infix[i]);
        }
        else if(infix[i]==')')
        {
            while(ostack.top()!='(')
            {
                cout<<ostack.top();
                ostack.pop();
            }
        }


    }
control=0;
    }
while(!ostack.empty())
{
cout<<ostack.top();
ostack.pop();
}
system("pause");
}
```

The problem is at the first **else if** statement in main function. when i debug there is no problem till there.But when i press the **"Step Into"** button from **(line 35(main line 14))** another read only file pops and shows

```
reference operator[](size_type _Off)
        {   // subscript mutable sequence
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2

        if (this->_Mysize <= _Off)

            _DEBUG_ERROR("string subscript out of range");

 #elif _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 1
        _SCL_SECURE_VALIDATE_RANGE(_Off < this->_Mysize);
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */

        return (_Myptr()[_Off]);
        }
```

that.

i changed inside of the **for** statement it works now but with error. the code looks like this now. when i enter **3*5-7/9**. output is 35*79/. but it should be 35*79/-.

```
for(i=0;i<infix.length();i++)
    {
        if(ostack.empty() && !isdigit(infix[i]))
            ostack.push(infix[i]);
    else if(isdigit(infix[i]))
    {
        cout<<infix[i];
    }
    else if(infix[i]=='+' || infix[i]=='-' || infix[i]=='*' || infix[i]=='/' || infix[i]=='^' || infix[i]=='(')
    {
        if(priority(infix[i])>priority(ostack.top()))
        {
            ostack.push(infix[i]);
        }
        else if(priority(infix[i])<=priority(ostack.top()))
        {    
            while(!ostack.empty())
            {
            temp.push_back(ostack.top());
            cout<<ostack.top();
            ostack.pop();
            }
        control++;
        }
        else if(control=1)
        {
        ostack.push(infix[i]);
        }
        else if(infix[i]==')')
        {
            while(ostack.top()!='(')
            {
                cout<<ostack.top();
                ostack.pop();
            }
        }


    }
control=0;
    }
```

Comment: Your second set of code is the runtime code.  We know that works correctly, so it does little help posting it.  BTW, `main` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Where in *your* code does the "crash" happen?

Comment: @user3322385 Indentation would help.

Comment: Note: The order of tests is wrong here: `if(priority(infix[i])>priority(ostack.top()) || ostack.empty())`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i changed it to int,nothing changed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg at main line 14

Comment: @user3322385 My comment was on your usage of non-standard syntax, not a fix to your code.  The probable fix to your code is what Dieter suggested -- move that test for stack empty to the beginning of all of your tests.  If it's empty, push an item and go get the next character.  Don't combine it with other tests -- it also makes the code more clear.

Comment: You have a problem here `else if(control=1)` where the condition will always be true, as it sets `control` to 1 every time.

Comment: @BoPersson i forgot that. i add the control = 0 at the end of for statement

Answer (score 1):

This condition in your code

```
if (priority(infix[i]) > priority(ostack.top()) || ostack.empty())
```

is already an immediate indication that the code is broken.

If there's a possibility that `ostack` is empty (and there is, since you are checking for it), then calling `ostack.top()` is illegal. And apparently this is exactly what your code attempts to do.

If you want to check for `ostack` being empty, you have make sure that you do it *before* calling `ostack.top()`, not after

```
if (ostack.empty() || priority(infix[i]) > priority(ostack.top()))
```

In this order specifically (!), not the other way around.